# Pantalla de Ajustes en Odoo 14

Tags: odoo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tocando por primera vez odoo(version odoo 14), investigando las distintas opciones y módulos que tiene y en algún momento se me cambió la pantalla de ajustes que venía por defecto y no se como volver a ella, actuamente tengo la pantalla de ajustes de la foto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Busca en los grupos de Usuario por la palabra clave **ajustes**.
2. Te aparecerá el grupo **Administración / Ajustes**, agrega tu usuario y
   listo.

Te anexo una captura. [image: Captura de Pasos en Odoo]

Saludos